# NoClassDefFound Error but I can see the class in dependencies

Tags: spring, maven, noclassdeffounderror

I'm facing a NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/event/TransactionalEventListenerFactory when I try to run my Spring/Maven project but I can see that the missing class (TransacationalEvenListenerFactory.class) is on one of the dependencies that I added with Maven. That dependency (spring-tx) can be seen in the Maven Dependencies part inside my Eclipse
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUGkx.png)

I know it may be a silly problem but I'm not getting it

Comment: I guess what you have is spring-4.2.0 release, but what the code might be referring to some other version?

Comment: Try checking the "Dependency Hierarchy" tab in Eclipse. Type `spring-tx` in the search field and check if your expected version of spring-tx (4.2.0.RELEASE) is being omitted by some other transitive dependency.

Comment: Please post your POM.

Comment: Checked the Dependecy Hierarchy and it's compiling spring-tx 4.2.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it, sorry. There was another error thrown that I wasn't paying attention to related with org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory . I changed the version of spring-context dependency to 4.2.0 an it worked.